# Touchpad click instead of movement

Tags: windows, touchpad

I've connected a USB touchpad to my Windows 7 desktop machine to get something that can generate a mouse click without requiring mechanical force. It works, somewhat, the only problem being that it's very difficult to touch it without generating any sideways movement at all, which causes the system, more often than not, to interpret the action as a small mouse movement instead of a click.

What's the best way to do any of the following?

1. Tell the system to assume it was a click if the movement was less than e.g. ten pixels.
2. Tell the system to assume everything from the touchpad is always a click instead of a movement.
3. Otherwise generate mouse clicks without mechanical force.

Comment: Doesn't your system have settings for trackpads? Most built in trackpads have user interfaces for customising movement sensitivity, etc.

Comment: @MrLister, not that I can see; it's a desktop machine, so the trackpad is just something I bought separately, not built in, and the mouse/pointing device entries in control panel/device manager don't seem to have anything; am I missing something?